# Make my SSH I treat like VPN more anonymous

Tags: ssh, vpn, server, anonymity, tor

I have a VPS (although I could easily upgrade to a dedicated server) which I use as a "poor man's VPN" by tunneling through it.

My aim is to improve this server so anyone attempting to track me has a hard a time as possible. Defeating the NSA would be nice, but it's realistically not possible, so as long as regular law enforcement (or adversaries with their capabilities) cannot track me I am satisfied.

**My ideas are the following:**

> - Run as a Tor and i2p relay, also use freenet so there are always numerous connections making it hard to pinpoint who was using the server (a relay also keeps the IP address clean from black lists)
> - Ensure all logging is off
> - Full disk encrypt
> - Have deep freeze (or a linux equivalent) enabled
> - Run everything from RAM
> - Randomly restart at times I am not using it
> - Perhaps chain 3 different servers together using IPTables or something similar so it takes any investigators through 3 different countries
> - Ensure offshore country with strong privacy laws, and countries which outright hate the country I am hiding from (so if USA then pick
>     Russia etc)
> - Pay anonymously with BTC
> - Linux OS
>
>   - Regularly change servers

The server itself will be secured, updated software, SSH key with long password, nonstandard SSH port etc...

I am aware that even if company honestly keeps no logs their ISP most likely will, however hopefully with the above I can make it very difficult to discover which connection I was.

What else could I add to increase the anonymity of tracking me?

Comment: The only way to ensure anonymity is to not use *your* computer at all. Use a computer at the public library. Make sure there are no security cameras. Don't tell anyone your real name. Don't log in to any personally-identifiable services on the computer (Facebook, email, SSH to server in your name, etc.) If you suspect someone might have reason to trace the connection, never use that computer again (or any computer in that building).

Comment: @Dan Yes I am aware of that. However, lets focus on this question which is about the SSH.

Comment: My point was, it *doesn't matter* how you configure SSH, you're not anonymous when you're doing anything via an internet connection where the bill is in your name. There's no gray area when it comes to anonymity; you're either anonymous, or you're not.

Comment: @Dan So pretend I did what you said, except I still want to use my SSH just to increase the amount of time I have to ermmmm flee the country, or whatever?

Comment: There's a reason I wrote "Don't log in to any personally-identifiable services on the computer (e.g. SSH to server in your name)". It's best not to use it at all.

Comment: Perhaps if you reword the question to "more difficult to track" rather than "more anonymous", since the latter doesn't really make sense. You can't be any "more anonymous" than you can be "more dead". Anonymity is binary.

Comment: @Dan Once again thank you but I am well aware. Server will not be in my name (paid for with BTC too). True I will update. EDIT no actually I clearly explained in description: My aim is to improve this server so anyone attempting to track me has a hard a time as possible. Defeating the NSA would be nice, but it's realistically not possible, so as long as regular law enforcement (or adversaries with their capabilities) cannot track me I am satisfied.

Comment: I have to disagree that anonymity is binary. Few things in the real world are binary. Virtually nothing you can do online or IRL leaves absolutely zero forensic traces, it all depends on the resources and motivation level of any attacker(s). So perhaps better to focus on the threat model(s), resourcest needed to address them, and effectiveness of those efforts.